# Is is possible to bind a XAML ItemSource to an IEnumerable generated by a Where query?

Tags: c#, linq, xaml, windows-phone

I am creating a Windows Phone Application and would like to use Pivots to show different views into the same data.

To do this, I created properties:

```
IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; set; };
IEnumerable<Item> ItemView1 { get { return Items.where(value => value.Property) }};        
IEnumerable<Item> ItemView2 { get { return Items.where(value => value.Property) }};
```

And then I bound to them in my view:

```
<phone:PivotItem>
    <phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding ItemView1}">
</phone:PivotItem>

<phone:PivotItem>
    <phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding ItemView2}">
</phone:PivotItem>
```

And after adding items to the `Items` property, I call:

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("ItemView1");
NotifyPropertyChanged("ItemView2");
```

How ever, when I run the application, my view does not get updated with the new results but it works if I create new lists.
Is it not possible to bind directly to the result like this?
If not, is there any suggested way I should be doing something like this, hopefully without having to build multiple lists all the time?

Comment: Can't you change it to `Items.Where( x => x.Property).ToList()` it should work fine after you fire NotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Have you tried "{Binding Path=ItemView1}"?

Answer (score -1):

You're raising the wrong event.

Simple content bound controls, like text blocks, etc., autowire up to INotifyPropertyChanged, if the context object implements that interface, but collection based controls (I think selector based as well) look for INotifyCollectionChanged.

Comment: I do not know why this answer has -1 reputation, but @JerKimball is right. 'ItemsSource' dependency property subscribes for 'INotifyCollectionChanged' event. So, you have to use 'ObservableCollection' or create your own implementation of collection implementing 'INotifyCollectionChanged' interface.

Comment: For more details you can look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613546(v=vs.110).aspx): "In order to get the ListBox to pick up the changes, you would have to recreate your list of employees and re-attach it to the ItemsSource property of the ListBox."